# AngularJS Dynamic Form Validation Based from Select box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a fairly straightforward directive to ensure some basic sanity checks on whether a form field contains a valid phone number or a valid email depending on which select box option is chosen (Email or Text).
The issue arises after a valid email or phone number are entered corresponding to the selection made, and the other choice is selected, the field being validated remains valid even though it should not be a valid entry any longer.

I am stuck at how exactly to have the field revalidate through the directive when the select option is changed.

My directive is as follows:

```
directive("rpattern", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            scope: {
                service: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
                var validator, patternValidator,
                        pattern;
                scope.$watch(function() {
                    if (scope.service == 'Text') {
                        pattern = new RegExp(/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[ .-]?(\d{3})[ .-]?(\d{4})$/);
                    } else if (scope.service == 'Email') {
                        pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/);
                    }
                });
                patternValidator = function(value) {
                    return validate(pattern, value);
                };
                ctrl.$formatters.push(patternValidator);
                ctrl.$parsers.push(patternValidator);
                function validate(regexp, value) {
                    if (value == null || value === "" || regexp.test(value)) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('pattern', true);
                        return value;
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('pattern', false);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
A plunker has been created here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7CMj8t5TzkkXMUOLzgF?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried angular validations as per this link http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html   You can try ng-pattern if you want to perform a regex. If you do not want to use that then do revert back will try to fix this directive for you

Comment: My issue isn't using a regex itself or alone the issue is that based on a previous form field choice I need the ability to change which regex is being used.  One regex is easy with ng-pattern or with this directive modified to only use one regex, the issue is with the changing and revalidation of the input.

Comment: Have you tried to change your watch to $scope.$watch('service', function() {}? If not I hope that helps.

Comment: Yea that is what I tried originally which is why I switched it to what is seen above.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddler for the same. I have to paste some code hence putting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by adding the line patternValidator(ctrl.$viewValue); within the watch worked to revalidate the field on the select element change.  I am not sure if this is the best way of doing so but it does work.  I have updated my plunker to reflect this change in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to put the call to validate inside the watch like:

```
directive("rpattern", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            service: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            var validator, patternValidator,
                    pattern;
            scope.$watch(function() {
                if (scope.service == 'Text') {
                    pattern = new RegExp(/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[ .-]?(\d{3})[ .-]?(\d{4})$/);
                } else if (scope.service == 'Email') {
                    pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/);
                }
            patternValidator = function(value) {
                return validate(pattern, value);
            };
            ctrl.$formatters.push(patternValidator);
            ctrl.$parsers.push(patternValidator);
            });
            function validate(regexp, value) {
                if (value == null || value === "" || regexp.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pattern', true);
                    return value;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pattern', false);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```